# Add ssl certificate on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

i'm trying to add the ssl certificate on heroku but still show this message.

```
Resolving trust chain... failed
Unable to read server.pem file
```

anyone getting problem?

thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a the **default error message if anything goes wrong** with add/update certificates call on heroku.

It may be some misspelling or incorrect command . you have to figure it out.

Can see **following links for reference**:

[SSL Configuration Unable to read server.crt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590752/ssl-configuration-unable-to-read-server-crt-file)

[Heroku SSL Configuration Unable to read server.crt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096098/heroku-ssl-configuration-unable-to-read-server-crt-file)

[Configuring SSL for an App Heroku HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597207/configuring-ssl-for-an-app-heroku-https)